# How can I get a team together to make a game

Tags: teamwork

I’m interested in making games and I have some ideas, basic programming and art knowledge. How can I get together a team of people who have more skills than I do to help make the game?

Comment: Have you checked out the advice regarding game jams in some of the Q&A threads I linked earlier? These are great ways to meet like-minded developers and begin to build friendships and a track record for being a good collaborator / making cool stuff that others want to contribute to. If you're looking for a faster route: do you have budget to pay contractors or employees?

Comment: Please consider the tags you are using & if necessary check the guidance when selecting question tags. The question isn't about the process of deciding the rules and mechanics of a game, and solving balancing problems to achieve the intended play experience.